# Getting specific string in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server 2008, I want to get the year of following string format. Parameter will be one of following strings (`DateTime.MinValue` and `DateTime.MaxValue` from C#):

'1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM' and '12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM'

Here is my expected answer:

```
0001 from 1st string.
9999 from 2nd string.
```

Comment: try date_format function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know what the format of the input string is, you can just do:

```
SELECT ... SUBSTRING([Input], PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', [Input]), 4)
FROM   ...
```

Or

```
SELECT ... SUBSTRING([Input], CHARINDEX('/', [Input], 4) + 1, 4)
FROM   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be another way to do the same as well.

```
declare @test nvarchar(50)
SET @test='1/1/9999 12:00:00 AM'
declare @testdate date
set @testdate=CONVERT(date,@test,101)
select DatePart(year,@testdate)
```

Check out this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f34be/2)